# Problem in sending HTTP PUT request using Apache HTTP client & Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-httpcomponents, http-put

I have developed a simple REST API which serves a simple HTTP PUT request using Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE & Oracle JDK 14. Below is the server side REST endpoint:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/documents")
public class DocumentController {

   @PutMapping(value = "/setCurrentTenant", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<?> setCurrentTenant(
             @RequestParam(value = "documentId", required = false) Long documentId,
             @RequestParam("tenantId") Long tenantId) {
        return documentService.setCurrentTenant(documentId, tenantId);
    }
}
```

And the client side code:

```
HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8080/api/document/setCurrentTenant");
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    
builder.addTextBody("documentId", "1");
builder.addTextBody("tenantId", "10");
HttpEntity setCurrentTenantEntity = entityBuilder.build();
putRequest.setEntity(setCurrentTenantEntity);
httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);
```

I tried to run the code and everything is okay but when the client request is sent to the server, Spring would log an exception like this:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
 Required Long parameter 'tenantId' is not present]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should send `tenantId` as request parameter like

http://localhost:8080/api/document/setCurrentTenant?tenantId=10

I'm concern that why are you consume a multipart/form-data while you're not sending any file/binary data

---

```
class TenantRequest {
  Long tenantId;
  Long documentId;
  //seter, getter
}

@PutMapping(value = "/setCurrentTenant", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> setCurrentTenant(TenantRequest request) {
 // TODO
}
```

or

```
@PutMapping(value = "/setCurrentTenant", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> setCurrentTenant(@ModelAttribute TenantRequest request) {
 // TODO
}
```

Comment: It should be inside of request because of security reasons

Comment: If so you RequestBody or ModelAttribute annotation and create a request object to map request parameters

Comment: That's not my problem, and I see there are a lot of other ways to do that. But why does not it work while everything is okay??